# Dropbox стоит ли доверять и насколько?

Tags: dropbox

Многие начали использовать его для хранения конфигов, паролей (естественно защищенных) и др..   
Но меня интересует вопрос доверия и еще один вопрос: если удалю на своем компе папку Dropbox, что будет? Исчезнут ли те 2 гига и у них на сервере? То есть, если у меня рухнет винт и полетят все данные, то останутся ли они в облаке?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ввиду того, что в облаке хранится **копия** данных, они не пропадут. Первоначальная задача этого сервиса состояла в онлайн-бэкапе информации. То есть чтобы можно было восстановить её в случае порчи или утери.

Файлы хранятся на сервере даже если вы их удалите у себя. (Хотя есть возможность их удалить совсем)

Насчёт надёжности и защищённости от неправомерного доступа - точно не знаю. Но судя по описанию - подход там вполне серьёзный. ([How secure is Dropbox?](http://www.dropbox.com/help/27))

Answer (score 1):

При хранении данных на облачном сервере вы теряете контроль над своими данными. Если вы храните в Дропбоксе резервную копию музыки, картинок, видео то доверять можно. Но хранить пароли от всего там, куда вы не имеете физического доступа я считаю ребячеством.

Comment: Пароли нужно хранить в одном месте. В голове!

Comment: qwerty- это сила!
а вот если из 30 символов?
я храню их в keepass под одним паролем,а в нем разные пароли без повторения

Answer (score 0):

Клиент DropBox копирует файлы на сервер. Если вы просто удалите программу данные останутся на сервере. Более того DropBox хранит разные версии файлов. Насчет доверия не знаю, не думаю что они просматривают все файлы в надежде найти что-то ценное. Более того облаком занимается серверы Amazon, так что это вопрос к ним, DropBox просто сервис. Насчет применения люди часто используют сервис для хранения данных игр, браузеров и т.д.

Answer (score 0):

Если паранойя мучает, то шифруйте все файлы, которые будете туда заливать. GnuPG - хороший выбор. И тогда никаких вопросов такого рода возникать не будет.
Касательно доверия скажу такую вещь, что когда вводите пароль в окне регистрации на любом сервере, то Вы ему пароль автоматически доверяете несмотря на то, что пароль в открытом виде на сервере не хранится. Но возможна ситуация компрометации ресурса. А, учитывая, что парольная комбинация у многих людей на разных ресурсах одинакова - можно поиметь "кражу личности" ;-)

> То есть, если у меня рухнет винт и полетят все данные, то останутся ли они в облаке?

Однозначно. Тут даже такой прикол есть, что многие онлайн сервисы даже сохраняют пользовательские данные, когда пользователь удаляет их оттуда. Т.е. существует скрытая копия. Опять же - вопрос доверия.